# Confluent 5.3.0 - missing confluent shell script

Tags: confluent-platform

I am trying to start Confluent 5.3.0 on Ubuntu and need some help.

The first thing I tried was navigating to **confluent-5.3.0/bin** and running **sudo ./confluent start** (because that's the way I've been starting Confluent 5.2.1).

This gave an error message: **sudo: ./confluent: command not found**.

I then checked the folder **confluent-5.3.0/bin** and found it's missing a shell script named **confluent**, which is included in 5.2.1.

I checked the Release Notes and the Quickstart. Both of them say I should start Confluent with **confluent local start** instead of **confluent start**. (See screenshot at bottom). However, I still get the same error message because the shell script is still missing: **sudo: ./confluent: command not found**

[image]

For those of you who are able to start Confluent 5.3.0, how are you doing it? Can you paste your command line here?

Did you have to write your own **confluent** shell script for 5.3.0?

Can I just copy my **confluent** shell script from 5.2.1? I'm assuming it must be incompatible, since they removed it from 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 5.3.0 you will have to install CLI separately

https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/installing.html#cli-install

```
curl -L https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -b /path-to-directory/bin
```

Then you can run

```
confluent local start  --path <path-to-directory>
```